Has our knowledge of astrophysics and gravity reached the point where we can accurately calculate Lagrange points?
is it possible for us today given the knowledge we possess of gravity and our success with inserting satellites in to steady/ geosynchronous orbit and any knowledge we have on  the relative size (and there fore gravitation effects) of celestial bodies in our solar system would we be able to calculate an exact location that we if placed an object at location X that in a vast number of years later that the competing gravitational pull of the already existing spatial objects would ensure that remains in the same place (kind of like dropping a buoy at sea that  once there regardless on the tides/currents we know bouy 45678y is at ocean position 45678Y

A significant problem is the accurate charting of all potentially relevant astrophysical objects in a system. This is a nearly impossible task, so you will always pick up a certain degree of error in any practical calculations that will need to be dealt with.

A buoy is anchored to the sea floor and GE is currently running short on vacuum anchors, I am afraid. I heard they had a production backlog since 1947, when that device was patented. OK, jokes aside... the solar system is a chaotic environment. The different orbital periods of the planets keep tugging on things and because there is no dissipation these forces can lead to resonant buildup of orbital motion even (or better, especially) near Lagrange points. One can stabilize spacecraft actively against these influences, but a small body without active control will not be long term stable.

This might be of interest - What Makes Lagrange Points Special Locations In Space

There are no true Lagrange points in the Solar System. Lagrange points represent solutions of the restricted three body problem, but the Solar System is a many body system.
There are orbital regions that approximate Lagrange points, but objects in them do not rigidly stay in the "same place" relative to their co-orbital bodies.

Tru enough, but several of the planets in our solar system have their "trojan" companions that have been hanging out near the planet/Sun L4 or L5 point for a good long time.

@SolomonSlow Indeed, but they move around within regions: they don't stay in the "same place" in the sense of the OP.
